# shopify app gives 429 and 401 errors when registering webhooks at installation - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, shopify-app

I have developed an app using the `shopify_app` gem in ruby on rails. I have also added sidekiq gem for run background jobs. I have setup `shopify_app.rb` with webhooks like below:

```html
config.webhooks = [
    {topic: 'shop/update', address: ENV["option_domain"]+'/webhooks/shop_update', format: 'json'},
    {topic: 'app/uninstalled', address: ENV["option_domain"]+'/webhooks/app_uninstalled', format: 'json'}
  ]
```

When I install the app, it gives me 401 unauthorized and 429 too many requests errors.

How to resolve it?